# codeigniter case when inside where not working?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->where("(CASE WHEN 'tbl_products.is_seller_product'='0' THEN 'tbl_stock.stock_item_stock' > '0' ELSE 'tbl_products.qty_dummy' > '0' END)");
```

Comment: case when is meant to be at select not where.

Comment: but it is working fine in laravel , but not in codeigniter

Comment: in that case, the safer way is to use query() function after the ->db command. So it will look like this $this->db->query('your full query string here')->result();